How to make an expanding card in a grid just affect the layout of it's own column and not all
Using CSS Grid, I have a 2x grid of cards that are expandable. My problem is when one expands, it pushes all cards beneath it down in both columns. What I'm wanting is the cards beneath it in the same column to be pushed down. Masonry does not solve this problem as when a card expands it still pushes every column down. Anyone have any advice? Thanks :)

.provider_list {
    height: 80vh;
    overflow: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.card {
    height: 12em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: .7em;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    width: 28em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}


function expandCard(button) {
    let card = button.parentElement;
    if (card.style.height == '30em') {
        card.style.height = '12em';
        button.innerHTML = 'More Details'
    } else {
        button.innerHTML = 'Hide Details'
        card.style.height = '30em';
    }
}

<div class="provider_container">
    @if(count($providers) > 0)
    <div>
         <p class="count">Provider Count: {{ $provider_count }}</p>
        <div class="provider_list">
            @foreach ($providers as $index => $provider)
                <livewire:provider :provider="$provider" :key="$provider['number']"/>
            @endforeach
            @if(!$hit_query_total)
                <form wire:submit="loadMore">
                    <button type="submit" class="more_button">Load More</button>
                    <span class="loading_indicator" wire:loading>
                        Searching...
                    </span>
                </form>
             @endif
        </div>
    </f>
    @else
        <h3>No Providers..</h3>
    @endif
</div>


<div class="card">
    <div class="content">
        <span>Name: {{ $lname }}, {{$fname}}</span>
        <span>NPI: {{ $npi }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="more_details">
        <p>Here is some additional information that will be shown when the card expands. You can put more details or any other content here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="more_details_button" onclick="expandCard(this)">More Details</div>
</div>

